# django reversing url failure with hyphen in view name

Tags: django, django-templates

My first question, so please be patient if I miss key info or not format it correctly.

I recently started experimenting with django and run into the following error:

> Reverse for 'dispatcher' with arguments '(u'to-do',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

the relevant line in the template.html (I am showing a menu) is:

```
    <li><a href="{% url 'dispatcher' item|slugify %}">{{ item }}</a></li>
```

I also includes {% load url from future %} as I read in some other question on this forum.

I have few other items in the list, such as 'today', 'tomorrow' etc. and as long as I don't have a hyphen I don't get any error. If I remove the hype, i.e. instead of to-do use todo, everything works.

snippet of my urls.py is:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    url(r'^$', 'home', name="home"),
    url(r'^items/(?P<item>\w+)/$', 'dispatcher', name="dispatcher"),
```

)

Whether relevant or not, I tracked down to iri_to_url function in encoding.py and saw that hyphen is not part of 'safe'list. But adding '-' to the list didn't solve the problem.

Appreciate your advise and help.

Comment: try `|safe` instead of `|slugify`. Does it help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex does not support the `-` Hence the error. change `\w+` to `[\w-]+`

Try this:

```
url(r'^items/(?P<item>[\w-]+)/$', 'dispatcher', name="dispatcher")
```

Comment: thanks! this was indeed the problem. Silly cut&paste mistake.